# API to connect Symbian OS device

Tags: c#, c++, symbian

I need to connect the Symbian OS device and communicate with files. Is there any api or dll to connect device to do this? I need to back the contacts,photos and other possible files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect how? Packet data, USB, Bluetooth? With Bluetooth there's the [OBEX API](http://www.symlab.org/wiki/index.php/Symbian_OS_Communications_Programming/10._OBEX) - it can be used via USB as well, but there are probably more quirks with getting it to work.

If you are using Qt, you can do this with [QBlueToothTransferManager](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility/qbluetoothtransfermanager.html#details).

Comment: Thank you teukkam, Connect via USB only. Is it possible to backup sms,mail,contacts,calendar,task,history,etc using this method and extract the backup file.